# how use ajax- dynamic- list inside the div tag

Tags: jquery, facebox

How use ajax- dynamic- list inside the div tag. The div tag displayed in the facebox.

Answer (score 0):

Working from your (very limited) details, I would say that you would use the standard jQuery actions to create the "ajax- dynamic- list" within a DIV in the page (which you can hide using css through `style="display:hidden;"`).

You would then display the content of that DIV using the method shown on the [Facebox Documentation Page](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) under "Divs".